# what is wrong with my code ? java script chart position

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, chart.js

I'm trying to set my two Chart.js as horizontal position. but unfortunately my two charts div does not response to the style. Does any one know what is issue with my code.

```
   <style>
    #Bar {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        top: 0px;
    }

   #Pie {
        position: absolute;
        left: 500px;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        top: 0px;
    }
</style>



<div class="Bar">

    <label for="myChart">
        Bar chart Title <br />
        <canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="250"></canvas>
    </label>
</div>


<div class="Pie">
    <label for="myPieChart">
        Pie chart Title<br />
        <canvas id="myPieChart" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
    </label>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You use css `id(#)` selector, but you have `class(.)`es on your div's. Change `class`es to ids.

```
<div id="Bar">

    <label for="myChart">
        Bar chart Title <br />
        <canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="250"></canvas>
    </label>
</div>


<div id="Pie">
    <label for="myPieChart">
        Pie chart Title<br />
        <canvas id="myPieChart" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
    </label>
</div>
```

Or change style's selectors to classes (use `.`).

```
.Bar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

.Pie {
    position: absolute;
    left: 500px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

**Example**

```css
#Bar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

#Pie {
    position: absolute;
    left: 500px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Bar">
    <label for="myChart">
        Bar chart Title <br />
        <canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="250"></canvas>
    </label>
</div>


<div id="Pie">
    <label for="myPieChart">
        Pie chart Title<br />
        <canvas id="myPieChart" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
    </label>
</div>
```